# @SpringbootApplication does not scan components in default package

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi I have my main class of spring boot app in package com
and two other beans defined in com.bbh.fx.pack1.

As per my understanding SpringBootApplication will autoscan all the components in its pakacge and childern package. But it is not scanning. Not sure what i am missing

```
    **package com.bbh.fx.pack1;**

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

    @Component
    public class BeanA {

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            System.out.println("in BEANA");

        }
    }

   **package com;**

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MainApp{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
       }
    }
```

Comment: SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args) in main method

Comment: just assuming you do not have a main method in MainApp (see @Georgy Gobozov his comment )... Am I wondering how did you test or launched your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a main in your MainApp your code should look like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
   }
}
```

I usually like to start all new applications from https://start.spring.io/ you can choose your project name, build type (maven or gradle) and select any spring dependencies you'd like included in the application.

Comment: i added main to MainApp, it still does not auto detect BeanA

Comment: Can you add your pom/gradle build. Are you missing any dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Use @ComponentScan to scan components.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com")
public class MainApp{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
   }
}
```